# The Youtube-API for "Videos: insert" is not working properly

Tags: youtube-api

I'm trying to upload a video using the YouTube API.
I'm using the code snippet provided in the documentation page:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert
I'm using the Python API.

I'm running this after providing a valid client secret file and file to upload.
I was able to authenticate using auth2, and provide a valid token.
I'm getting the following response:

```
{'kind': 'youtube#video', 'etag':   '"wdgS91PsEbtTfi20GmzFuZzYg2s/75EL94ZW60lJpJbXGn80dBaJI00"', 'id': 'Rz0n45vusps', 'snippet': {'publishedAt': '2020-05-30T05:23:07.000Z', 'channelId': 'UCAfompGqO1DYLi1WZ9GPYiw', 'title': 'Test video upload.', 'description': 'Description of uploaded video.', 'thumbnails': {'default': {'url': 'https://i9.ytimg.com/vi/Rz0n45vusps/default.jpg?sqp=CIDax_YF&rs=AOn4CLCt23wHAw-ViyVPCn5Sbxdh0v9Nzw', 'width': 120, 'height': 90}, 'medium': {'url': 'https://i9.ytimg.com/vi/Rz0n45vusps/mqdefault.jpg?sqp=CIDax_YF&rs=AOn4CLCshm-pBB2CeHW5ynQkhS4TA7zBWA', 'width': 320, 'height': 180}, 'high': {'url': 'https://i9.ytimg.com/vi/Rz0n45vusps/hqdefault.jpg?sqp=CIDax_YF&rs=AOn4CLDwNiO2tURd2POhFKrYOh6vYTfN6A', 'width': 480, 'height': 360}}, 'channelTitle': 'jvalansi84', 'categoryId': '22', 'liveBroadcastContent': 'none', 'localized': {'title': 'Test video upload.', 'description': 'Description of uploaded video.'}}, 'status': {'uploadStatus': 'uploaded', 'privacyStatus': 'private', 'license': 'youtube', 'embeddable': True, 'publicStatsViewable': True}}
```

But I'm not seeing the actual video in my uploads.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the video was a duplicate. I first uploaded manually, and then tried to use the API.
It would make sense to have some kind of feedback that the video is a duplicate through the API though.